# PHP does not updates

Tags: php

So I'm currently running php **5.5.34** on my mac.

I tried installing php 5.6 via :-

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6
```

However, after installing when I ran **php -v** , it again gave me **5.5**

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit.

`php --ini` output

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/php5/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/php5/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/php5/php.d/10-extension_dir.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/20-extension-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/40-curl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/40-openssl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-apcu.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-curl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-gmp.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-igbinary.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-imap.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-intl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mcrypt.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-memcached.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mongodb.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mssql.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-pgsql.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-propro.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-raphf.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-readline.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-redis.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-solr.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-ssh2.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-xdebug.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-xsl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/60-extension-pecl_http.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini
```

Comment: Have you checked libphp5.so has been disabled on the new installation?

Comment: what do you get when you run `php --ini` ?

Comment: on macs, youre better off using homebrew for your installations. Its just much easier especially when dealing with extensions

Comment: Read https://php-osx.liip.ch/ on the sections for **Why does php -v on the command line still show my old version?** Re-installs into new directory, Uninstall and Reinstall. As noted on the site's twitter feed, homebrew is far easier to maintain. In essence add: `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` for the new installation of php of your `~/.profile` file.

Comment: ...or MacPorts!

Comment: make sure to backup as youre doing this.